# Unable to use any of the API of Zephyr Scale Server API (v1). Showing 404 Status / Dead Link issue

Tags: postman, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I am trying to use APIs from this **https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-server/api-docs/v1/** documentation, where I am Unable to get the response. I am fulfilling all the specified requirements as mentioned in above documentation.

```
http://{My_Jira_URL}/jira/rest/atm/1.0/testcase/{Test_Case_ID}/attachments
```

The Auth type which I am using is Basic.

Here is a response which I am getting in postman

[image: Here is a response which I am getting in postman]

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong | what could be the **cause behind** this issue.
Or Else **any alternate way or API resources** to get Attachments for Jira-Zephyer Test cases?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Zephyr scale API token as authorization to get a response for the APIs.
https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-cloud/api-docs/#section/Authentication

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).